# Calculate grand median in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Let's say I want to calculate the grand median for a table for a continuous column X. One could use this code snippet:

```
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY X)  
    OVER (PARTITION BY 
        ?
    )
AS grand_median
```

The OVER PARTITION BY part is mandatory though. Why is this when I want to calculate the grand median? What can I do please? Thanks!

PS: just to add some artificial data - already with answer inspired by @Paweł Dyl

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Data') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Data

CREATE TABLE #Data
(
    Number FLOAT,
)

INSERT INTO #Data (Number) VALUES (30);
INSERT INTO #Data (Number) VALUES (20);
INSERT INTO #Data (Number) VALUES (42);
INSERT INTO #Data (Number) VALUES (42);
INSERT INTO #Data (Number) VALUES (42);
INSERT INTO #Data (Number) VALUES (43);
INSERT INTO #Data (Number) VALUES (40);

SELECT * FROM #Data

SELECT DISTINCT PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Number) OVER() FROM #Data
```

Some R code to 'test' this:

```
test <- c(30, 20, 42, 42, 42, 42, 40)
median(test)
```

The correct answer is of course 42.

Comment: @SeanLange - IMHO the question should be quite self explanatory without the need to create some artificial data and tell people what the median of a few numbers is!

Comment: OK good luck. Maybe I am missing something in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OVER` is mandatory, `PARTITION BY` is not. See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-cont-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014) and following demo:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    X int
)

INSERT @table VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(10),(12)

SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY X) OVER() FROM @table
```